# Watch a movie from the middle of it from the start

Tags: word-usage

If I want to specify when I started watching a movie (a scene)

> I watched the movie from the start.
>
> I watched the movie from the scene where they _______.
>
> I watched the movie from the middle of it.
>
> I watched the whole movie; from the start to the end.

Do these sentences sound natural?

Answer (score 2):

## Yep!

Honestly, though, your last sentence might be a little better if you said:

> I watched the whole movie; from start to end.

Notice how I didn't overuse "the" there.

It also might be a good idea to use "beginning" instead of "start" for all of your sentences because that is a common way to talk about movies, elapsed periods, books, etc.

Comment: Why the semicolon in your example?   Don’t you mean to use a comma?